# How to change the current tab highlighter color in Android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

Here is my layout inside `ViewPager`. I would like to change the color of the current tab highlighter which is below the text. Actually it is showing in black color. But I don't know whether it is a color by default or not. And also I have one more doubt. If I use `PagerTitleStrip` this tab highlighter doesn't appear. Is there a way to bring that with titlestrip?

Here is my layout:

```
  <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/pager_titlestrip_bg"    
    android:textColor="@color/pager_titlestrip_text"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" >   
  </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>
```

Comment: I have looked into JakeWharton ViewPager Indicator solution. For me the tabs along with swipe just works fine. But I want to change the tab indicator color. There is option to change the tab textcolor. But not the indicator color. It is showing as black by default.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This just works.

```
PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about XML only?

Answer (score 13):

It can be done in both programmatically with jAVA or with XML

By XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Or more simply you can solve this Code aswell

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Similarly to change the Height

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (2 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in my project.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/text3"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text3"
    app:tabTextColor="#000" />
```