# Change Color TabSelector on v4 ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view, android-tabs

Is it possible to change color of selected tab on [v4 ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)?
I need to use v4 ViewPager, but I don't find any source to customize it.
Just to clarify I need to change the blue color to another one:

[image: TabSelector]

Comment: have u checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408080/how-to-change-the-current-tab-highlighter-color-in-android-viewpager

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the tab indicator. You can change its color by applying different styles.

Use [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), generate 9patch png files (tab_selected, tab_selected_focused etc.) and add these files + styles to your project.

Another approach -> [How to change the current tab highlighter color in Android ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408080/how-to-change-the-current-tab-highlighter-color-in-android-viewpager) (as @Pratik wrote in comment).

Comment: it does not work at all. I am using tab swipe WITH FRAGMENT ACTIVITY

Comment: Please refer to esme_louise's answer. I was having trouble too but his clue saved my problem. I suppose it solve yours as well.

Comment: And you might also make sure you have chosen the right option in "style compatibility". By default it is Holo and if yu are using Appcompat or Sherlok it will not work properly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on an Answer, but regarding the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) make sure after you add the files to the corresponding folders in your project that you also add the theme to your manifest xml file like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.whatever.myapplication.YourActivityName"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Whatever_you_named_your_style_in_the_generator">
</activity>
```

Comment: For future visitors: In manifest you may need to set the whole app theme (not just an activity). like this:<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.the*name*you*chose" 
        android:name="****">

Answer (score 2):

The `ViewPager` is not the one you need to customize. You need to set the `tabIndicatorColor` of the `TabLayout` linked with it in the layout.

Dynamically you could do

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_id);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(R.color.your_color); // here
```

Inside the XML, that would be as simple as the following

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way i don't find the way to customize the tab. So i have fixed it using

```
<View
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headertab1"
       android:layout_above="@+id/viewpager"
        android:background="#0066CC" />
```

I have put this code with each 3 tabs belove the tab & above viewPager.
As we can detect that which tab is selected very easily.
So we can use this 'line1' visibility to View.VISIBLE or View.INVISIBLE.

Hope it helps to you!!