# Change ActionBar tabs color

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-tabs, android-styles

I am using the appcompat support library and I want to change the color of the **action bar tabs**. I found these [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) in which the **customize tab indicator** section suggests creating a file res/drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator.xml declaring a specific background image for several different states of an action bar tab.

actionbar_tab_indicator.xml looks like :

```
<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />

...
```

The @drawable/* images are nine patches.
However, i do not want to get involved in creating nine-patches images. Is there another way to change the actionbar tab's color?

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Color TabSelector on v4 ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077457/change-color-tabselector-on-v4-viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an answer to that question 1 year ago.

You can find in here:
[Change Color TabSelector on v4 ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077457/change-color-tabselector-on-v4-viewpager/18077617#18077617)

Comment: So, the only way  to change the actionbar tabs color is to create 9 patches(either creating them manually or automatically by the site you provide)?

Comment: It's the easiest and the fastest way to do that. But you can do it programmatically as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486571/is-it-possible-to-change-actionbar-tab-indicator-programmatically

Comment: @zoevas Did it help you? Or you need a different approach?

Comment: Yes, i have used the action bar style generator! Thank you!